# Java - Webcam shot/video with Mac and Windows x86 & x64

Tags: java, video, stream, webcam, capture

I want to access the built-in or USB webcam on Mac and Windows(32-, and 64bit) with java. How do i achive that? Any useful APIs or other things like that?
I don't want to install something. It should be in an API and some .dll's e.g. - so that my runnable .jar file is portable.

I googled everything. I tried JavaCV, JMF, JMyron but nothing worked for me - that sucks -.-"

I hope somebody can help me.

Comment: "...  but nothing worked for me" Why not? What problems did you have?

Comment: Did you tried [VLCJ](http://code.google.com/p/vlcj/)

Comment: Are you saying that [this applet here](http://code.google.com/p/javacv/wiki/HowToMakeAnApplet) doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a JNI call and talk to the webcam driver/API provided by vendors.

OR

If you are lucky to have a TWAIN compatible webcam, you can use JTwain APIs

Links:
[`http://www.twainforum.org/`](http://www.twainforum.org/)
[`http://www.programmersheaven.com/2/Java-Twain-image-acquisition`](http://www.programmersheaven.com/2/Java-Twain-image-acquisition)